# Validation and display issues?

Tags: html, css, browser, xhtml

I am developing a website for a friend which was earlier developed by some other guy, basically, I am a PHP pro and don't ve much experience in HTML (or until now) ...

now, I am trying to validate my webpage, earlier it was showing 162 errors, I 've brought it down to 1 error (thank you) ... haha

earlier with 162 errors, it was looking good in firefox3 but not loading at all in ie6 or ie7 .....

now since I 've managed to get it down to 1 error, it's looking good in Firefox as usual and loads on ie6 and ie7 as well but not rendering properly in ie's .... page layout is a bit garbled.

the only error which remains now is .... Attribute "height" exists, but can not be used for this element. .....

now when I take care of all these mistakes ... i.e removing height="100%" in tables .... even firefox refuses to show it properly.

Please point me in the right direction ... I 've been working on this whole site for the last five days .. and it's pro-bono ....

I don't know the rules about posting links .... anyways ... here's the link for the page I am talking about ...... I hope I am making sense ...

http://www.shivgangaresorts.com/dev/aboutus.html

please view this page in ff3 and ie6 or ie7 to see what I am saying .... any help would be greatly appreciated ....

thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might try using style="height: 100%" instead of height="100%"

Most height/width properties on tags assume you are talking about pixels, so it doesn't know what your '%' character means.

See this [article](http://apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php).

Answer (score 0):

Before all, 100% as property on any element, in almost all cases are stupid. None of browsers applies correctly 100% value.

But, if you're trying to validate your document, quit the 100% value from  and put it on a separate CSS class. e.g:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now i hope that your document comes valid! haha

Regards!